# Why does not Bower work?

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

**Projects are identical**

First

```
PS C:\Users\khdev\Desktop\test> bower init
C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\bower-config\lib\util\rc.js:92
                throw error;
                ^

Error: C:\Users\khdev\.bowerrc should not be a directory
    at C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\bower-config\lib\util\rc.js:90:25
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at json (C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\bower-config\lib\util\rc.js:87:14)
    at rc (C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\bower-config\lib\util\rc.js:34:13)
    at Config.load (C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\bower-config\lib\Config.js:16:20)
    at readCachedConfig (C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\config.js:15:39)
    at defaultConfig (C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\config.js:11:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\index.js:16:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
PS C:\Users\khdev\Desktop\test>
```

Second

```
PS E:\Все для Web Верстки\Project\Toy> bower init
bower existing      The existing bower.json file will be used and filled in
? name (toy)
```

Bower does not work on drive "C", but on drive "E" everything works.

Comment: try deleting C:\Users\khdev\.bowerrc

Comment: Looks like your .bowerrc file is messed up.

Comment: .bowerrc found in "C: \ Users \ khdev \ Desktop \ test", but it did not help. I deleted and bower.json and this also did not help.

Comment: .bowerrc

{
 "directory": "app/libs"
}


With the path to the folder and spelling all okay.